# Getting firebase storage image 403

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Next.js and am struggling to get firebase storage images to render on screen as they keep coming back as 403 errors.

I upload an image to storage when adding a document to firestore with a url nested in it then use that url to get the image

This is my Next Image tag with recipe.main_image.url == https://storage.googleapis.com/example.com/recipes/0O3Oycow4lJvyhDbwN0j/main_image/190524-classic-american-cheeseburger-ew-207p.png

And recipe.main_image.name == the name of the photo in firebase storage.

```
<Image 
  alt={recipe.main_image.name}
  src={recipe.main_image.url}
  width={650}
  height={650}
/>
```

The alt tag comes back as the right thing (image name in firebase storage) so I know the image is getting sent back but for some reason I'm unauthorised I've tried multiple fixes including changing firebase rules to

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

AND

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

But neither change the outcome I've also set my next config up so I'm getting firebase storage

```
  images: {
    domains: ['images.ctfassets.net', 'storage.googleapis.com'],
  },
```

Comment: Do you intend to serve the image to the public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images will be served to the public, then i would suggest to grant public access to the image. Cloud Storage for Firebase is backed by Google Cloud Storage. You can [**make individual objects publicly readable**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#objects) or [**make the bucket publicly readable**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets).

or better yet, generate [**signed URLs**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), this way you can grant limited time access to an object. If you're working with Javascript then you may take a look at this sample code on how to generate a signed URL.

```
/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 * Note: when creating a signed URL, unless running in a GCP environment,
 * a service account must be used for authorization.
 */
// The ID of your GCS bucket
// const bucketName = 'your-unique-bucket-name';

// The full path of your file inside the GCS bucket, e.g. 'yourFile.jpg' or 'folder1/folder2/yourFile.jpg'
// const fileName = 'your-file-name';

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

async function generateV4ReadSignedUrl() {
  // These options will allow temporary read access to the file
  const options = {
    version: 'v4',
    action: 'read',
    expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  };

  // Get a v4 signed URL for reading the file
  const [url] = await storage
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .file(fileName)
    .getSignedUrl(options);

  console.log('Generated GET signed URL:');
  console.log(url);
  console.log('You can use this URL with any user agent, for example:');
  console.log(`curl '${url}'`);
}

generateV4ReadSignedUrl().catch(console.error);
```

You may visit this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-generate-signed-url-v4) for more information.